# what's the state of java thread when socket io.read() can't get any data

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

as titled, what's the state of java thread when socket io.read() can't get any data.
Many articles mentioned the io will be blocked, but jdk say blocking occured in getting lock monitor?
how to understand it?

Answer (score 2):

If the thread is waiting for I/O, my understanding is that it's in the [`RUNNABLE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html#RUNNABLE) state. It gets into the [`BLOCKED`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html#BLOCKED) state when it tries to synchronize on an object that is locked by another thread. It is in the [`WAITING`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html#WAITING) state when it calls `wait()` (or a couple of other methods).